# Digital Signing - Which files are required apart from DLLs?

Tags: .net, code-signing

In our current .net projects(web and windows), we are providing digital singing on DLLs only.

As a best practise do we need to sign all other files as part of deployment objects like JavaScript file,CSS,Config files,MSI,Exes, PowerShell Script also?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is best practice to sign files that you distribute, although many people don't due to various reasons, such as the price of obtaining a certificate or the hassle of getting the certifying authority to validate who they are before issuing it.

However only some types of files can be signed, this includes common types like DLLs, EXEs, MSIs and PS Powershell scripts.

You cannot sign other files like XML or zip files. If you want to deploy files that cannot be directly signed then you can include them in a container that can be signed, like:

- create a self extracting zip (.exe) to contain them
- ship them as an embedded resource in a file that is signable